# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, javascript, qa-developer, database

When you running below Jmeter test plan then "Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' response message given. Can any one have any solution for this?

Response code: null 0
Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the JDBC driver class in your path? I'm assuming the class is on your computer.

Comment: After adding MySQL Connector/J in to the Jmeter lib folder as @Dmitri T mentioned below now its working fine. Thanks all for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you forgot to add MySQL [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to JMeter (JMeter doesn't include it by default)

1. Download [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
2. Extract `mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx-bin.jar` and drop it somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (for example to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter to pick the jar up
4. You should be good to go

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) for more detailed explanation and instructions